# Get a copy of a large (160000+ internal object tree) object

Tags: c#

Ok, I have a set of very large, identical, trees cached in memory (to be populated with non-identical data [they contain information about stuff inside each node]).

I want to copy a single instance of the tree, and populate each copy with a seperate set of data.

However, at the moment, the cached 'blank' copy of the tree is not being copied, but simply referenced and filled with every single set of data.

How can I force the method that gets the cached blank tree to return a copy of the object, instead of a reference?

Comment: what classes do you use to handle your tree structure and do that classes support ICloneable interface ?

Comment: It's a custom tree class, it's built from scratch for optimisation of a search/classification problem, and thus had to be insanely lightweight for speed purposes: each tree contains well over 160k nodes, and this is the optimised version, the naive implementation that it overtakes would have over 10x that. thus, no it's not set to support icloneable.

Comment: I've read the comments you've posted to the other answers here and I think you need to clarify some. You say you want a copy, but you're saying it would be rather insane to copy the original tree. What exactly is it that you want to do? There is no mechanism in .NET save for the ICloneable interface to do anything like this, so you're going to have to write code no matter what you end up with. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I was hoping to return a copy of the object from my function, in a similar way to the way you can in C++, however it seems that C# has no ability to do so. I think simply re-creating the tree may be the best way to go.

Comment: C++ has no magical Clone() either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Clone() - serialize it in the memory binary stream and then deserialize as a new instance.

**EDIT**

Also, if you will consider serialization, and if performance is you primary concern, please also take into account the following performance test [Manual Serialization 200% + Faster than BinaryFormatter](http://www.intellectualhedonism.com/2009/06/16/ManualSerialization200FasterThanBinaryFormatter.aspx).

Comment: if you think that either serialization or manual recursive copy will not give you the performance you need, then I suppose you should use C++ unmanaged code to be able effectively store you tree in memory and copy with memcpy... but unmanaged code it is not an area where I can make very valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but I recommend implementing `ICloneable` on the tree object, and then call `Clone()` to create a deep copy.

Comment: Actually implementing ICloneable is not usually recommended.

Comment: Any reason for that? If I have to implement a recursive deep copy, then I'd rather do it with a documented interface. How you implement the Clone() doesn't matter, you can do Object.MemberwiseCopy, use serialization or assign all fields yourself

Comment: @Chris: IClonable kind of missed it's goal, so it is _no_longer_ recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look closely at your tree classes, and if you are going to be enforcing copy semantics, then use `struct` instead of class. Else use `ICloneable` interface to provide Clone() method, as chris166 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

With such a large tree, having multiple copies of it will incur a lot of memory overhead. Why not just organise the data at each node (with a Dictionary, for example) so that it holds all the different data (as you're getting at the moment), but organised in a way which is convenient to your actual need?

Comment: the memory overhead is less of a concern than the processing overhead, in this case. each node already contains a dictionary full of data for the tree's specific dataset, adding this data into another dictionary would be too much processing when generating the tree.